# CanCan: 'can' method fetch records again, even if they already fetched

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, cancan

I'm trying to pass an object like that

```
    <% if( can? :change, comment.karma, comment.user_id)%>
        #blah blah blah
    <% end %>
```

and in my ability.rb i have the following:

```
    can :change, Karma do |karma, owner_id|
      !karma.changers.map(&:user_id).include? user.id and owner_id != user.id
    end
```

And every time I refresh the page cancan fires a query (from `ability.rb`) to get karma and then changers for that karma, even through I have already fetched it (using `:include => { :karma => :changers }` option for query in controller).

**Added:**

I have a guess that it's happening because karma is storing a link to :include objects (not objects itself), which is actually get broken when I pass it to method. So I'm thinking about serialization now..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the query in the model try using this syntax

`@comments = Comment.where(:foo_id => Bar.id).includes(:karma => :changers)`

and see if the problem persists.

For reference, http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface has a great rundown of the new rails 3 active record querying syntax.